# Intermittent "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" while inserting record into SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

I am experiencing the `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime` when inserting a record into SQL, from a website. This only happens maybe once out of 200 or so record inserts.

Basically, the the site asks for a date input from the user and the date should always be in MM/DD/YYYY. I have put TextBox masks and Regular expressions in place to make sure of this, also having tested several times myself.

However, there are still intermittent cases where the site throws the exception during SQL store.

My setup includes a web server and then a separate SQL server. (Maybe time difference between both?)

**My code for SQL insertion for the date input is as follows...**

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientDateOfService", Convert.ToDateTime(PatientDateOfServiceLabel.Text));
```

I use this same template (and stored procedure on my SQL server) on other sites hosted on the same web server with no problem. The issue only occurs on one particular site. 
I got to thinking maybe this was a time-zone or culture related issue.

After some extensive research, I was wondering if using the CultureInfo class may help me. I am pondering on the following change to my code and was wondering what others may think as well..

```
// Call a new instance of the CultureInfo method and set to en-US
CultureInfo USCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");

// Insert the date with newly added CultureInfo instance
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientDateOfService", Convert.ToDateTime(PatientDateOfServiceLabel.Text, USCultureInfo));
```

Might this help in resolving my issue?

-Thanks

Comment: What is the value of `PatientDateOfServiceLabel.Text` exactly? And what is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: Start logging the value of `PatientDateOfServiceLabel.Text` when the exception is thrown. You'll likely find a pattern your existing validations are missing.

Comment: @Soner Gönül The value of PatientDateOfServiceLabel.Text is always of format MM/DD/YYYY. For example, the user may enter 05/21/2014 on an input page and then they are taken to a confirmation page to see the label. After an online payment transaction, my code inserts the date directly from the label. Our culture is en-us. Or at least is should be. We're in Texas which is central us time.

Comment: There could be something wrong with the validation on form letting them input something like 13/02/2014 and when it gets to converting it fails.  The other problem would be if the current culture is being set to something other than en-US then 02/13/2014 might fail.  I agree with @JoelCoehoorn that you should log the values and you will most likely see a pattern.

Comment: the exception is telling you the issue - you're trying to convert strings to datetimes, and they aren't in the correct format.  The `Convert` class throws a `FormatException` when the string can't be converted - catch it, log the invalid string, and continue throwing the exception.

Comment: Is error generated by SQL Server or by 'Convert.ToDateTime' code?

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn I'm with you on that. I get email records with the exceptions. Interesting, I put the exception and details in the email AND I put data directly from the labels. Every piece of data shows up but the date is always blank. I don't see how this happens because I have a required field validator that is not supposed to allow blank fields to be submitted. Some how the data gets lost.

Comment: @PrzemG The source is always mscorlib

Comment: Do you do server-side validation too? If you use ASP .NET validator control it validates client-side only by default. It could be that page is accessed by user with javascript disabled and validation does not work allowing to post back with that field empty.

Comment: @PrzemG I do, after client-side validation, it is then validated on the server after post-back

Comment: @PrzemG I wonder if somehow the data in my "Date" label gets lost while the site communicates with the payment processor. The site is a bill payment site and only after the site gets a response from a payment gateway does it insert a record into SQL. I wonder if during that processes, my label some how goes blank. My logs alway show blank for the date label and the log it's self gets data directly from the labels as well.

Answer (score 0):

Although I cannot seem to find any articles to support this assertion, the AddWithValue method automatically converts strings to valid SQL-Server DateTime values. It is safer, however to explicitly denote the data type by using the Parameter.Add method instead, ex.

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(PatientDateOfServiceLabel.Text, SqlDbType.DateSqlDbType.Date);
```